# How can I convert timestamp to date format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there's a way to convert a timestamp to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` date format?
I can convert it to ISO using `toISOString` but it add `Z` at the end of the string.

Thank you.

Comment: @isherwood "X" refer to the ISO 8601 time zone

Comment: The value is `+00:00`.

Comment: moment.js is very useful for these kind of conversions

Comment: @VincentChinner, I know, but I would like to avoid using it if possible

Comment: Have you thought about just removing manually the ``Z`` ``str.substring(0, str.length - 1);``.I know isn't the best solution but does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();

var datestring = d.getDate()  + "-" + 
                 (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + 
                 d.getFullYear() + "-T " +
                 d.getHours() + ":" + 
                 d.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below code to convert timestamp to date format.

var date = new Date(timestamp*1000);

var year = date.getFullYear();

var month = months_arr[date.getMonth()];

var day = date.getDate();

var hours = date.getHours();

var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();

var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

Display date time in any format you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to use an external library like moment.js (which i would strongly recommend), as you stated in your comment, you will have to implement a function for that yourself, as regular javascript does not provide a function for this (as far as i know).

You can create an object of javascripts built-in `Date` class from a unix timestamp by using

```
var unixTimestamp = 1566394163;

//multiply with 1000 as Date expects milliseconds
var date = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000);
```

Then you could build the output string yourself, by using something along this

```
var dateString = "";
dateString += date.getUTCFullYear()+"-";
dateString += date.getUTCMonth()+"-";
dateString += ...
```

On the other hand, if the `Z` at the end of the string is the only thing that bothers you about the format provided by `toISOString()` as a workaround you could use its output and remove the last character of it

```
var dateString = date.toISOString();
var newDateString = dateString.substr(0, dateString.length -1);
```